# .htaccess displays 500 internal server error instead of expected 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-500

I have a problem with my .htacces code, because it produces an 500 internal server error instead of a 404 error, like it should.

The 500 internal error is only caused if I try to open a page in a directory which is actually a file. For example, in the root of my website, there is the file `biography.php`. `https://example.com/biography.php` redirects to `https://example.com/biography/`.

But when I try to open the non-existing page `https://example.com/biography/test/`, it shows an 500 internal server error instead of the expected 404 error.

This is my .htacces code. The last 6 lines seem to cause the issue, because without them, the expected 404 error is displayed instead of the 500 internal server error. But without them, `https://example.com/biography.php` doesn't redirect to `https://example.com/biography/`…

Maybe there is a redirect loop or something like that? I just copied the code from the internet, so I'm not able to troubleshoot it myself.

```
Options -Indexes
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
ServerSignature Off
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !(^$|\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^((/?[^/]+){1,2})/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Thank you for your help! I hope you can understand my issue! I appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

The rewrite-loop (which causes the 500 error) is caused by the last rule (3 directives) because the condition that checks `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` is not necessarily checking the same file that you are rewriting to in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string (ie. `$1.php`).

When you request `/biography/test/` you end up checking whether `/biography.php` exists (which it does), but you end up rewriting the request to `/biography/test.php` (which does not exist) - which causes a rewrite loop.

See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/989351/49157) to the following question on ServerFault for a more detailed explanation: https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error

The last rule should instead be written like this:

```
# Rewrite to append the ".php" extension as required.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

This now checks that the target file exists before appending the `.php` extension to *the same URL-path*.

There's no need for two *conditions*. And the `NC` flag is not required here.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301]
> ```

However, your redirect to *remove* the `.php` extension is not strictly correct either. This will also erroneously remove the `.php` "extension" should it appear in the query string part of the URL. And you are missing the `L` flag. You also don't need both *conditions*.

Use something like the following instead:

```
# Remove ".php" extension from requested URL-path
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

#### Summary

```
# Remove ".php" extension from requested URL-path
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite to append the ".php" extension as required.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```